# How can I verify text exist within a table with db using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, database

Using selenium Webdriver+Java- I am looking for a way to identify and or verify a value in a table. There are more columns in the table, but I am only 
concerned with the Country column, Also the number of rows varies as well as the location of the value I am looking for.

So, say, I am looking for Country there. the country = “Germany”, who could exist in any row 1 to 9 or 10 or 20 etc.How could I locate and verify that user exist with Database query?

```
**Company**                 **Contact**        **Country**
Alfreds Futterkiste           Maria Anders        Germany
Centro comercial Moctezuma    Francisco Chang     Mexico
Ernst Handel                  Roland Mendel       Austria
Island Trading                Helen Bennett       UK
Laughing Bacchus Winecellars  Yoshi Tannamuri     Canada
Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti  Giovanni Rovelli    Italy
```

HTML Table Code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the country name from ui and verify that country name is exist in database using java code.

Comment: Do you need to check that the country value is *in* the database, or do you need to check that the country value is in the data that's displayed on the page? The answer to your question will be different if you need to check the database than if you need to find the data on the page.

Comment: Yeah I think they are confusing database table and HTML table. If you're looking for database than you don't need selenium at all.

Comment: I need to get the country name from ui and verify that country name is exist in database using java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(on mobile, sorry for formatting)

```
String country = "Germany"

// All ui rows
List<WebElements> rows = driver.findElements('tr');

// Is there any row with Country?
Boolean existOnUI = !rows.stream().filter(
              row => row.findElement('td:nth-of-type(3)')
                        .getText().equals(country))
                        .isEmpty();

//If so, is there some row with Country on the DB?

Boolean existOnDB = !dbDriver.execute("Select * from Table where country =" + country + ";").isEmpty();
```

The variables existOnDB and existOnUI hold information if the country exists.

Comment: I will try and tell you

Comment: Can you please make code properly,not able to understand